# IIS worker process making high memory usage

Tags: .net, performance, memory, cpu

I have deployed my web site on a development machine with 8 GB RAM, IIS 8.5 and .Net 4.5.2.

Same web site is deployed on Production machine with 4 GB RAM, IIS 8.5 and .Net 4.5.2.

For a particular request, the worker process on Production server uses 150 MB of memory and for the same request on Development server, the worker process takes 1100 MB of memory.

Also that particular request has a response time of 2-3 sec on my Production server whereas Development server is taking 20-40 sec of time.

As per my understanding this is not something related to code, but still can someone help me in the direction of whats the reason of this huge difference in memory usage and the response time on both the servers?

Though the Development server is more capable in terms of Memory and Processor, but still its performance is poor as compared to Production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Worker Process using a LOT of memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245727/iis-worker-process-using-a-lot-of-memory)

Comment: No, its a different case. In my case memory is not being used consistently. Worker process releases memory after completion of request

Comment: Grab a memory profiler, take snapshot during request processing and look what are placed in memory.